# How to solve this error in POSTMAN: "the PHP GD extension is required, but is not installed"

Tags: php, xampp, laragon

I got this problem in POSTMAN when I try to do a GET petition to get a base64 string (I want to obtain a PDF file), I´m using XAMPP and WINDOWS 11.

In XAMPP I've already have installed and enabled GD extension and have the same error message in postman. Even in my php.ini file and the environment one too.

Can someone help me?

PD: I have tried with laragon server too but does not work. And I have PHP 8.0.30

[Here is my php info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgvb9.png)
[Here the dll extension in xampp/php/ext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dvfy.png)

I have reinstalled xampp and laragon. But does not work and Im expecting to get a base64 string from my postman api.

Comment: That's not a postman error; that's a PHP error that suggests that the GD extension is not loaded.  If you have updated your php.ini you'll have restart your php service.

Comment: I have already restarted my xampp and laragon servers, even the computer.